# Java framework for portlets

Tags: liferay, portlet

Which is the best (easy to learn, feature rich) Java framework for creating portlets?

I will be targeting [Liferay Portal](http://www.liferay.com/products/liferay-portal/overview).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy to learn & Feature rich & RAPID: [Grails](http://grails.org) + [Grails Portlet plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/portlets)

Answer (score 1):

We are using spring it seems very feature rich
And easily learnt